# Apache MPM_Prefork Setting for high performance

Tags: mpm-prefork

My VPS has 16GB RAM / 6 Cores and it's running on Debian 10 with Virtualmin installed. and my script needs mpm_php to work properly.

Getting high traffic so I need to adjust the default setting of the mpm_prefork settings. i read mpm_worker or events cannot work with mod_php.

Here is my current setting

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          60
    MinSpareServers       30
    MaxSpareServers       80
    Serverlimit           840
    MaxRequestWorkers     840
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Can someone tell if this setting is good for high traffic? or should I need to edit something?

Comment: Yes, you should edit your PHP script so that it no longer requires mod_php. Then you can get rid of it and move to FPM and mod_event (or just nginx). mpm_prefork cannot be made performant which is why everyone is abandoning it.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to change the script to not use mod_php.

Comment: I can't think of anything that mod_php adds that you can't rewrite. You can seek help with such programming questions on our sister site [so]. Possibly they have already been answered.

Comment: Sure, let me have a look there... Thank you